# How to split a string by multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split a column of data into multiple columns based on a condition  ",,".

But it should also split the data when it encounters ",,,,".

Basically it should also consider ",," as ",,,,".

My code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['data'] = data
df
df.columns = ['header']
final = df["header"].str.split(",,",n = 2, expand = True)
final
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to split a string with more than one delimiter,
you can use `re.split(string=your_string, pattern=',,,,|,,')`
after importing `re`.

If you need something specific for Pandas, I don't know that.